# How to change z-index only this id elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change z-index only this id elements ?

When i use this code ,all id in my page will change z-index.

I want to change z-index only id = `link-box` , `love-box` , `love-box_inner`

How can i do that ?

```
document.getElementById("link-box").style.zIndex="99999";
document.getElementById("love-box").style.zIndex="99999";
document.getElementById("love-box_inner").style.zIndex="999999";
```

Comment: You are only changing the `z-index` of those elements. But how it affects the layout depends greatly on your `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: You should set the position of elemet as **relative** or **absolute**

Comment: i set 3 id to absolute but not work

Comment: Post more of your HTML and CSS, the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your three elements, `#link-box`, `#love-box` and `love-box_inner` have
the default position of `static`, and as result, `z-index`, though set, has no effect.

In addition, you need to set `position: relative` on the three relevant elements.

Answer (score 0):

set firs style position relativ or absolute and new add this zIndex for example

```
document.getElementById("link-box").style.position="relative";
document.getElementById("love-box").style.position="relative";
document.getElementById("love-box_inner").style.position="relative";

document.getElementById("link-box").style.zIndex="99999";
document.getElementById("love-box").style.zIndex="99999";
document.getElementById("love-box_inner").style.zIndex="999999";
```